# Wordpress Post pages

Tags: wordpress

I am currently trying to develop a website using wordpress with the customizr theme.  Now my problem is, I would like to have all POST pages to appear on a customised page that I have created instead of the front page.  It doesn't seems to be an option in customizr theme for me to have my POST appear on the page where I want them.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy. Go to your dashboard. Click Settings-> Reading. Select radio button of "A static page (select below)". Now select font page that you want to show as font page and select posts page to show your post.